# Is it possible to save a One Note notebook as a landscape PDF?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-onenote

OneNote gives you the option of saving an entire notebook as a PDF file.  Unfortunately I can only seem to find a way for it to do this in portrait orientation, which doesn't make a lot of sense for my content.

It has been suggested during my Googling that I use a PDF printer to work around this, however this isn't a workable solution as OneNote, for some strange reason, will not allow the printing of entire notebooks.  I would have to do it section by section which wouldn't take an insignificant amount of time.

Does anyone know a way to force it to output in landscape.  An acceptable alternative solution would be a way to change the created PDF file from portrait to landscape, though I don't know how feasible this is.

Answer (score 1):

The document saves through Adobe Acrobat Distiller.

- Open Adobe Acrobat Distiller
- Rrom the Settings Menu > Edit Adobe PDF settings.
- Change the Default Page Size to be 11.0 x 8.5
- Save As 'landscape'.
- At the main screen of the Distiller change Default Settings to the newly created 'landscape'.
- Leave Distiller screen open.  Go to Internet Explorer and locate the notebook you want to PDF.
- Right click menu "Convert to Adobe PDF". voila!!

Change your Distiller Defualt back to Standard and then File > Exit Distiller.

Comment: From OneNote > Click on the ribbon > under view click Paper Size.  You have to change the paper size for each page, but that will Save them to the page size you want 'layout'. Don't worry if images/text falls off the new page size, they will be squeezed in to fit.  Found this after I posted the last one. - C Jackson

Comment: The above comment did the trick for me in OneNote 2016. I first thought my content would be clipped off the page.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Save As... the Notebook as an XPS file and then from the XPS Viewer printing out to a PDF Driver in Landscape orientation.

That gets around the inability of OneNote to print an entire notebook.

Answer (score 0):

you can go File > Print > Print Preview > Print range: Current section, Orientation landscape > Print... > Microsoft Print to PDF.

This will print all pages in a section, not the whole notebook. but hope it helps